# How to create instance of classes using multiprocessing BaseManager

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.6

I have placed classes in a list like this:

```
compare_ref_handler_list = [
        (RefType.REF_SEE, RefSee), # reworked
        (RefType.MENUSELECTION, RefMenu),
...
```

then I started the manager at the init method:

```
if self.is_running_multi_processing:
            multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register('TranslationFinder', TranslationFinder)
            multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register('Catalog', Catalog)
            for (ref_type, handler) in RefDriver.compare_ref_handler_list:
                handler_class_name = handler.__class__.__name__
                multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register(handler_class_name, handler)

            self.manager = multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager()
            self.manager.start()`
```

Now when I come to use instance of the class, I put use this code:

```
           with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
                result_raw_list = pool.imap_unordered(self.compareData, enumerate(self.input_data))`
```

then in `self.compareData` in create a new instance of registered class like this:

```
ref_type = entry[0]
ref_handler: RefBase = entry[1]

handler: RefBase = self.manager.ref_handler(self.orig_message.id,
                                               tf=self.tf,
                                               ref_type=ref_type)

but it gives me error:


handler: RefBase = self.manager.ref_handler(self.orig_message.id,
AttributeError: 'BaseManager' object has no attribute 'ref_handler'
```

Can you please explain to me how can I create the instance of the class here?

I was expecting to see the instance of the class created successfully as in the non-multiprocessing mode using:

```
handler: RefBase = ref_handler(self.orig_message.id,
                                               tf=self.tf,
                                               ref_type=ref_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods registered on the BaseManager are the names of the classes `ref_handler` references, not the name `ref_handler` itself. What you want to do is dynamically get the attributes on BaseManager through `getattr` function. So, this code:

```
handler: RefBase = self.manager.ref_handler(self.orig_message.id,
                                               tf=self.tf,
                                               ref_type=ref_type)
```

Should be changed to this:

```
constructor = getattr(self.manager, ref_handler.__name__)
handler: RefBase = constructor(self.orig_message.id,
                               tf=self.tf,
                               ref_type=ref_type)
```

(Notice, that to get the name of the class, you don't have to do `.__class__.__name__`, just a simple `.__name__` will suffice)

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I will come back to this once I'm ready. At the moment I'm onto something else but will inform you the progress once I am back to this. Thanks again for answering.